# Buscar palabras con al menos una letra mayúscula

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo obtener un listado con las palabras que contengan al menos una letra mayúscula en una cadena, sin repetir?

En mi intento solo me da como resultado la última palabra de la cadena es decir: You.

```
function Calculate()
{
    var str = "JavaScript is used in billions of Web pages to add functionality, validate forms, communicate with the server, and much more. JavaScript is easy to learn. You will enjoy it.";
    var res = "";

    var newAr = str.split(/[ .,]+/).filter(String);

    for(var i = 0; i < newAr.length; i++) {
        if(newAr[i].match(/[A-Z]/)) {
            var WordCapLetts = newAr[i];
        }
    }

    res += "<br>Palabras con al menos una letra mayuscula: " + WordCapLetts; 

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75310/discussion-between-ruben-and-mariano).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Estás machacando el valor de la variable donde almacenas la palabra con mayúsculas en cada iteración.

```
function Calculate()
{
var str = "JavaScript is used in billions of Web pages to add functionality, validate forms, communicate with the server, and much more. JavaScript is easy to learn. You will enjoy it.";
var res = "<br>Palabras con al menos una letra mayuscula: ";

var newAr = str.split(/[ .,]+/).filter(String);

for(var i = 0; i < newAr.length; i++) {
    if(newAr[i].match(/[A-Z]/)) {
        res += newAr[i] + " "; 
    }
}



document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Esto funcionaría. ya si lo quieres mejorar podrías almacenar las palabras en un array, iterar sobre el array poniendo comas y en el último elemento no ponérsela... Hay muchas formas

EDIT:
Para poder añadir las palabras sin repetir he usado una lista y he ido iterando.
EDIT 2:
Cambiada lógica para concatenar las palabras en mayúscula.

```
function Calculate()
{
var str = "JavaScript is used in billions of Web pages to add functionality, validate forms, communicate with the server, and much more. JavaScript is easy to learn. You will enjoy it.";
var res = "<br>Palabras con al menos una letra mayuscula: ";

var newAr = str.split(/[ .,]+/).filter(String);

var lista = [];

for(var i = 0; i < newAr.length; i++) {
    if(newAr[i].match(/[A-Z]/) && !lista.includes(newAr[i])) {
        lista.push(newAr[i]); 
    }
}

res+=lista.join(", ");


document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cómo puedo hacer para que no imprima dos veces la palabra repetida?

Comment: Pues entonces si tendrías que usar un array de String y a la hora de meterlo en el array primero harías un if comprobando que en el array no exista ya esa palabra. Ahora edito mi respuesta para que funcione como quieres.

Comment: todo el último `for` podrías evitarlo con `lista.join(", ")`

Comment: Pues si, no estoy demasiado puesto en JavaScript. Lo voy a modificar

Answer (score 10):

Depende qué definas por "*palabra*", y eso tiene mucho que ver con qué es una mayúscula. ¿Son palabras en inglés con letras de `a` a `z`? ¿Son palabras en español con además vocales acentuadas y `ñ`? ¿O en chino, sin mayúsculas?

**Palabras con al menos una mayúscula**. Una palabra que tiene al menos una mayúscula es una que tiene cualquier cantidad de minúsculas al inicio, seguidas de una mayúscula, seguida de cualquier cantidad de letras. Podemos definir el siguiente regex:

```
/[a-z]*[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*/g
```

Veamos el caso para español, mejor:

```
/[a-záéíóúüñ]*[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ][a-zA-ZáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]*/g
```

Y acá el resultado:

```js
var str = "JavaScript is used in billions of Web pages to add functionality, validate forms, communicate with the server, and much more. JavaScript is easy to learn. You will enjoy it.",
    regex = /[a-záéíóúüñ]*[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ][a-zA-ZáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]*/g,
    palabrasMay = str.match(regex);
    
if (palabrasMay) {
    var res = palabrasMay.join(', ');
    console.log('Palabras con al menos una letra mayuscula:', res);
} else {
    console.log('No tiene palabras con mayúsculas');
}
```

**Valores únicos**. Si además te interesa filtrar que no haya repetidos, podemos construir un [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set) (ES6, que sólo permite valores únicos) y volver a llevarlo a array:

```
let arrayUnique = Array.from(new Set(arrayOriginal));
```

o, en navegadores más viejos, viendo que sea el primer índice de cada elemento:

```
function valoresUnicos (valor, indice, array) {
    return array.indexOf(valor) === indice;
}

var arrayUnique = arrayOriginal.filter(valoresUnicos);
```

**Código:**

```js
var str = "JavaScript is used in billions of Web pages to add functionality, validate forms, communicate with the server, and much more. JavaScript is easy to learn. You will enjoy it.",
    regex = /[a-záéíóúüñ]*[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ][a-zA-ZáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]*/g,
    palabrasMay = str.match(regex);
    
if (palabrasMay) {
    var res = palabrasMay
                  .filter(function (v, i, a) {return a.indexOf(v) === i})
                  .join(', ');
    console.log('Palabras con al menos una letra mayúscula:', res);
} else {
    console.log('No tiene palabras con mayúsculas');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Una sencilla solución que **NO** usa `regex` es simplemente ver si la letra coincide con "esa misma letra en mayúscula". Para ello empleamos el método `toUpperCase`.

```js
const string = 'Mayus JS JavaScript esto no EstoSiQueSale'

//Creamos una lista de palabras
const toArray = string.split(' ')

// Guardamos las palabras que sean mayúsculas
const mayusculas = toArray.filter(filterFn)

console.log(mayusculas)

//Función de filtro
function filterFn(word) {
  // Vemos si la letra coincide con su mayúscula
  return [...word].some(letra => letra == letra.toUpperCase())
}
```

Answer (score 4):

También puedes usar la expresión regular para obtener las palabras con al menos una mayúscula. La función match() te devuelve un array con las coincidencias. Y al final usamos en ese array la función unique() para que elimine las palabras repetidas. Te dejo aquí un ejemplo.

```
function Calculate() {

    var exp = /([A-Z])\w+/g;

    var str = "JavaScript is used in billions of Web pages to add functionality, validate forms, communicate with the server, and much more. JavaScript is easy to learn. You will enjoy it.";
    var res = "<br>Palabras con al menos una letra mayuscula: ";

    var words = str.match(exp);
    var WordCapLetts = words.unique();

    res += WordCapLetts; 
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = res;


    }
    Array.prototype.unique=function(a){
      return function(){return this.filter(a)}}(function(a,b,c){return c.indexOf(a,b+1)<0
    });
```

Comment: La expresión regular coincide **a partir** de la primera mayúscula, pero no tiene en cuenta palabras que empiezan con minúscula y tienen una mayúscula.

Answer (score 4):

Se puede usar `map()` para recorrer el array y verificar si cada elemento tiene una mayúscula.

Luego, para obtener los valores únicos, se convierte en un `Set`, y finalmente en un array usando el operador spread como `[...elSetGenerado]`.

```js
var text = "JavaScript is used in billions of Web pages to add functionality, validate forms, communicate with the server, and much more. JavaScript is easy to learn. You will enjoy it.";

var get_words = str => {
 return [...new Set(str.split(" ").map(cur => {
 return /[A-Z]/.test(cur) ? cur : "";
 }).filter(cur => cur !== ""))];
};

console.log(get_words(text));
```

Comment: Hola Eduardo Sebastian, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Edítala para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué hace el código? ¿Cómo soluciona el problema expuesto en la pregunta?

Comment: La verdad que el código está bien. Es una lástima que no intentes transmitir lo que sabés... En cuanto al `map()`, estás devolviendo el valor actual si tiene una mayúscula, por lo que parecería más práctico usar `filter()`

Comment: Ahora lo edito, no tuve le tiempo

Comment: Ya lo editaste, gracias Marino